# Why kernel source is not installed

Tags: kernel

I want to install kernel source in Ubuntu 12.04 which is not installed. I have checked the same using the following command :

```
dpkg -s kernel
```

Output is Kernel is not installed no information available

Hence I have followed the following steps to install the same:

1.Installed the Dependencies by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libncurses5-dev git-core kernel-package fakeroot build-essential
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

1. Download kernel source by the following command:

   ```
   wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.5.tar.bz2
   tar -xvf linux-3.5.tar.bz2
   cd linux-3.5/
   ```

3.Compiled the source code to generate the .deb packages by the following command

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-spica kernel_image kernel_headers
```

1. Install the .deb packages (two .deb packages generated, one is to install the kernel headers, another one is to install the kernel image) by the following command

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
   ```

But after reboot it seems kernel is not installed (checked by dpkg -s kernel). Please tell where I am going wrong.

Also, In step 3, I guess I am installing a new kernel (named spica kernel_image) but during the boot up this new kernel is not showing as option.

Please help me

Comment: The fact that you can boot indicates that the kernel is installed :)

Answer (score 2):

The kernel package isn't called "kernel", it's called "linux-image-<version>-<type>".